# Python time as value

Tags: python, datetime, suds

I am trying to consume hp nnmi web services. But here you can see I am using milliseconds as value in `filter2.value = d_in_ms`, and this is not working for me. I am able to see result when I use values like `filter2.value = "1493078400000"`, Please tell me if we can use int values like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated

import datetime
import time
now = datetime.datetime.now()
currenttime = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
epochtime = time.mktime(currenttime.timetuple())
print epochtime
d_in_ms = int(epochtime)*1000

t = HttpAuthenticated(username='xxxxx', password='xxxx')

url = 'http://example.com/IncidentBeanService/IncidentBean?wsdl'

client = Client(url, transport=t)
filter1 = client.factory.create('ns2:condition')
filter1.name = "sourceNodeName"
filter1.operator = "EQ"
filter1.value = "DEVICE"

filter2 = client.factory.create('ns2:condition')
filter2.name = "lastOccurrenceTime"
filter2.operator = "GT"
filter2.value  = d_in_ms


filter = client.factory.create('ns2:expression')
filter.operator = "AND"
filter.subFilters = [filter1, filter2]

allincidents = client.service.getIncidents(filter)
print "Nodes in topology:", len(allincidents.item)

for i in allincidents.item[:]:
  print i
```

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: I am receiving the following error   `print "Nodes in topology:", len(allincidents.item)
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'item'`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am able to see result when I use values like filter2.value = "1493078400000"

According to this statement, it looks `filter2.value` should be a string.  That would suggest that you need to use:

```
filter2.value = str(d_in_ms)
```